# Do not add XElement if value is 0

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I am creating an XML (see function below):

```
public static string CreteInvoice()
        {
            string _dc;

            Mark pm = new Mark();
            XNamespace tu = "http://www.name.com";

            var item = QueryDb.InvoiceHeader;
            var TaxNr = QueryDb.MyCertificates.FirstOrDefault();
            _dc = TaxNr.CertificateTaxNumber;

            XElement root = new XElement(tu + "InvoiceRequest",
                                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "tu", "http://www.test.com/"),
                                new XAttribute("Id", "data"),
                                new XElement(tu + "Header",
                                    new XElement(tu + "MessageID", item.XMLMessageID),
                                    new XElement(tu + "DateTime", item.DateSentToFurs.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))),
                                    new XElement(tu + "Invoice",
                                        new XElement(tu + "TaxNumber", _dc),
                                        new XElement(tu + "IssueDateTime", item.DateOfInvoiceCreation.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")),
                                        new XElement(tu + "NumberingStructure", item.NumberingStructure),
                                        new XElement(tu + "InvoiceIdentifier",
                                            new XElement(tu + "BusinessPremiseID", item.BussinesspremiseID),
                                            new XElement(tu + "ElectronicDeviceID", item.ElectronicDeviceID),
                                            new XElement(tu + "InvoiceNumber", item.InvoiceNumber) 
                                        //  ,new XElement(tu + "TaxNrSeller", item.TaxNrSeller) <- problem when item.TaxNrSeller is 0 or empty
                                        )
                                    ));

            XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""));
            xdoc.Add(root);

            string xdocText = xdoc.Declaration.ToString().Remove(36, 14) + "\n" + xdoc.ToString();

            return xdocText;
        }
```

In code (above) i have marked where i should create an `XElement` only:
if `item.TaxNrSeller` is different than `0`.
If `item.TaxNrSeller` is `0` tag `TaxNrSeller` should not be applied.

If you need any more info please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, if you pass a null element, its skipped. So you should be fine with:

```
new XElement(tu + "InvoiceIdentifier",
    new XElement(tu + "BusinessPremiseID", item.BussinesspremiseID),
    new XElement(tu + "ElectronicDeviceID", item.ElectronicDeviceID),
    new XElement(tu + "InvoiceNumber", item.InvoiceNumber),
    item.TaxNrSeller != 0 ? new XElement(tu + "TaxNrSeller", item.TaxNrSeller) : null
);
```

> If content is **null**, nothing is added. When passing a collection items in the collection can be **null**. A **null** item in the collection has no effect on the tree.
>
> *Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882(v=vs.110).aspx*

Other than that, you can just construct objects manually (which is easier to debug). This way you can provide a `0` check yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
new XElement(tu + "InvoiceNumber", item.InvoiceNumber),
item.TaxNrSeller != null && item.TaxNrSeller != 0 ? new XElement(tu + "TaxNrSeller", item.TaxNrSeller) : null
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new method which refactors your code a little to create the Xelement node:

```
public static XElement CreateNode(XNamespace nameSpace, string nodeName, object value)
{
    return new XElement(nameSpace + nodeName, value);
}
```

Then in your method you can use it:

```
XElement root = new XElement(tu + "InvoiceRequest",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "tu", "http://www.test.com/"),
                    new XAttribute("Id", "data"),
                    new XElement(tu + "Header"
                        ));
root.Add(CreateNode(tu, "MessageID", item.XMLMessageID));
// etc...
if (item.TaxNrSeller != 0 || item.TaxNrSeller != null)
    root.Add(CreateNode(tu, "TaxNrSeller", item.TaxNrSeller));
```